# c# how i can hide crystal "SubReport" programmatically?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

iam using  viual studio 2015 and crystal report 
and i have tow subReport
how can i hide section or sub report when the row count is 0 or table empty

i try this :
1-go to section expert 
2-click in x-2 button
3-write this on formula

```
       if ({Alarms.ID1}>1) then true
        if (sum({Alarms.ID1})>0 then false else true
        if (isNull({Alarms.ID1}) then true
```

and try a lote but it dosn't work

but it dosnt work 
what is the probelm ??
what i shoud do ?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't fully describe what the code you have actually does. Please edit your question to be more descriptive so we can help you to the best of our ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the feature to allow to auto suppress when empty.

1. Go in the main report
2. Right click the subreport
3. select "format object"
4. Click the subreport tab
5. Check "Suppress Blank Subreport"

Once that is done just make sure all section in the sub report are actually properly suppressed when there is no data then the main report will detect it's empty and will not print it.

To check for empty you can simply do a count over the column of your dataset like the following. In the suppress of each section in the subreport simply put the following. If there is no count (no record) the section will suppress.

```
count({Alarms.ID1}) = 0
```

or you could use the long way and write the following if you prefer this syntax

```
if count({Alarms.ID1}) = 0 then true
else false
```

Comment: When you hide the subreport, the place is empty. Can I place another subreport on it?

Comment: @Dany that is tricky. You have multiple ways to do that. One would be to make another section in the main report underneath the section the subreport is currently in and put a suppress if the section above is not suppressed.